# React app opacity transition not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I’m working on a pomodoro clock in React and I want message text (ex. “Set a time”, “Focus,” etc.) and the play / reset button to fade out and in when the play / reset button is pressed. So pressing the play button would fade out “Set a time” and the play button then fade in “Focus” and the reset button once the timer starts.

This works fine in Firefox, but the fade in doesn’t work properly in Chrome, even when I try adding the `-webkit-` prefix vendor. I’ve also noticed in Internet Explorer the message element going back to 0 opacity after the fade-in animation.

You can checkout my code and a live demo at this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ellereeeee/pomodoro-clock/tree/browser-compatibility).

I use the [react-transition-group library](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/Migration.md) to apply the transitions to elements I want to fade when they dismount and mount.

The relevant JSX is at the bottom of PomodoroTimer.jsx, or here for convenience:

```
  <CSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName="fade"
    transitionEnterTimeout={500}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
  >
    {!this.state.timerActive ? 
    <h3 className="message" key="set">Set a time.</h3> :
    (this.state.time < 50) ? 
    <h3 className="message" key="done">Done.</h3> : 
    this.state.timerType == "Rest" ?
    <h3 className="message" key="rest">Rest.</h3> :
    <h3 className="message" key="focus">Focus.</h3>}
  </CSSTransitionGroup>
```

And the relevant CSS is in PomodoroTimer.css, or this:

```
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-out;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
}

.fade-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-leave.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: It does work perfectly in chrome in the sandbox link you have provided.

Comment: Hmmm that's odd, it still looks broken in my Chrome browser. Could you please try making the transition-duration longer in

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-out;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
}

and tell me if it works properly for you?

Even if I change the transiton from 500ms to 5000ms the fade in happens quickly and abruptly, while it properly transitions for 5000ms in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here is that you are changing animation time in css as below:

```
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 5000ms ease-out;
  transition-delay: 5000ms;
}

.fade-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-leave.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5000ms ease-in;
}
```

But here the **fade-enter** and **fade-leave** classes applies to element according to the time defined in below code:

```
<CSSTransitionGroup
   transitionName="fade"
   transitionEnterTimeout={5000}
   transitionLeaveTimeout={5000}
>
```

Here the classes defined above applies and being removed according to time defined here. So even if you make 5000ms to css animation duration and here you have transitionEnterTimeout={500} and      transitionLeaveTimeout={500}. So these classes will be removed or added after this amount of time.

Hence you have keep time same at both places.

Comment: Thank you, your comment made me more careful when I tried debugging my app. I've noticed that an opacity transition with a transition-duration and transition-delay of 500ms is visible in Firefox but not in Chrome. However, it's visible in Chrome if I make the transition-duration a bit longer. I think it's simply due to browser differences.

Comment: Yes, Usually different browser act differently in some situations. There are many cases like this for example embedded documents and HTML5 videos have different controls and look & feel for different browsers.

Hope this solves your problem, if it does please accept the answer.